# Writing a bash script to push local files to Amazon EC2 and S3 - needs proper owner/permissions

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, file-permissions, chown

I have a PHP project on my local machine, with the following folder structure

```
  assets/
  |- css/
  |- ...
  |- js/
  |- ...
  dynamic/
  |- scripts/ *contains a bunch of .php files
```

The plan was to push the `assets/` directory to Amazon S3 (for use with the CloudFront CDN) using `s3cmd` and to push the `dynamic/` files to the Amazon EC2 instance (web-server) directly.

The base script I'm using it below:

**[push.sh]**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Source our program variables
. ./_global.sh

# Setup the build directory
echo "======== Preparing the build directory =============="
node build/r.js -o build/build.js

# Start up the rsync to push the dynamic files
echo "==== Syncing dynamic files with the EC2 instance ===="
rsync -rvzh --progress --delete --exclude-from "${BUILD_DIR}exclude-list.txt" \
    -e "ssh -i ${BUILD_DIR}mykey.pem" \
    $WWW_BUILT_DIR ubuntu@$SERVER_IP:$SERVER_DIR

# Push the static assets up to S3
echo "========== Pushing static assets to the S3  ========="
s3cmd sync --delete-removed --exclude-from "${BUILD_DIR}exclude-list.txt" \
    ${WWW_DIR}${ASSETS} s3://mybucketname/${ASSETS}

echo "All done :)"
```

Everything works perfectly, **except** that the permissions on the files that were pushed to the EC2 web server are all set to the user that was configured in the `ssh` command (`ubuntu`). How can I set this to use `:www-data` instead?

Comment: Maybe you could set up a cron job as root that runs `chown` and `chmod` on the proper directories periodically?

Comment: @Paul yes I suppose I could, but that would leave a window where the files exist with invalid permissions (between the time when they were pushed, and the time when the cron job runs) that could be bad for business.

Comment: Well then you need a holding area where this sort of thing goes on, some directory you specify, and then when valid these things get moved or copied to production directories.

Comment: @Paul thanks for the help, but `JTheRocker`s answer below solved my problem nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After everything is done, you can put this in your script to execute commands remotely (e.g. chown, chmod and the like),

```
ssh -l root -i ${BUILD_DIR}mykey.pem" $SERVER_IP "chown whateveruser:whatevergroup $SERVER_DIR"
```

Syntax:

```
ssh -l root -i key $SERVER_IP "your command"
```

Comment: Glad that it helped you out!